# To stylize WP_Error messages or not?

Tags: wp-error

I hate, despise forcing markup/stylization on anyone that extends my system because I'm making assumptions about how my code is going to be used and force people to play around my decision-making.

Thing is, I'm now faced with an issue. I have a really long `WP_Error` message, it's like 100 salamis all put together long.

I kinda wanna insert a `\r\n` between these messages to make it readable.

Is there no middle-ground? I'm also offering these messages separated in the `error_data` but, of course, it'd be nicer to have it readable from the get-go.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to put all errors in a `debug.log` file using `error_log` and it would be readable enough as it includes break lines automatically.

I think not all the errors should be visible for clients.
In case that I need to show an error to the user, I check the error type and I show a short message with a custom code like **Sorry, Post ID is missing [error 12]** and the I know **Error 12** could happen in certain cases.